# How to draw part of a large BufferedImage?

Tags: java, graphics, rendering, bufferedimage

I have a 10000x10000 `BufferedImage` and I'm looking to draw only part of it to a `Canvas`, is there a way to do this using args such as:

`x, y, width, height` ?

So for example, drawImage(img, x, y, width, height) would draw a rectangle from the image starting at (x, y) and having (width, height) as the dimensions?

EDIT:

I'm going to re- word this question:

I have a 10000x10000 image and I only want to display a portion of it on the screen, the problem with just  offsetting it by x and y is that this still causes lag as the entire image is being rendered, just most of it off canvas. How can I basically make it so that the entire image is rendered but I can scroll around it without causing the canvas to lag?

Comment: I have edited the answer with response to your question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I have a 10000x10000 BufferedImage and I'm looking to draw only part
>   of it to a Canvas, is there a way to do this using args such as:

1. Don't use canvas for custom painting in java. use `JComponent` or `JPanel` instead. It has a nice function `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, override it and paint your image inside with `g.drawImage(x, y, width, height, observer)`;
2. Swing graphics has `Graphics.clipRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)` to bound the area rectangle to which you wish to draw prior to drawing the image.

**Edit (In response to your edited question):**

First approach is to use `BufferedImage..getSubimage(x, y, width, height)` to get a sub image with specified rectangle region. It is faster.

```
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("file")); 
    img = img.getSubimage(50, 50, 500, 500); // 500 x 500
```

This function will give you a new image cropped with the `rectangle(x, y, width, height)` of your original image you specified. Use the returned image to draw on your component.

**Tutorial resource:** [Clipping the Drawing Region](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/clipping.html)

---

**Demo: Demonstrating clipping Image with Animation:**

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

class MyCanvas extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
  public BufferedImage buffImg;
  public Rectangle rectangle;
  Random random;
  long lastTimeChanged;
  int dirX = 1, dirY = 1;
  volatile static boolean imageLoading = true; 
    public MyCanvas() {
        random = new Random();
        rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 250, 250);
        lastTimeChanged = System.currentTimeMillis();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 

        if(imageLoading)
        {
            showWaitForLoading(g);
            return;
        }

        g.clipRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
        g.drawImage(buffImg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);

    }


    public void showWaitForLoading(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(getWidth()/2-100, getHeight()/2-15, 200, 30, 30, 30);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.drawString("Loading image...", getWidth()/2 - 45, getHeight()/2 + 3 );
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(endTime - lastTimeChanged > 500)
        {
            dirX = random.nextInt(2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
            dirY = random.nextInt(2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
            lastTimeChanged = endTime;
        }

        if(rectangle.x < 0)dirX = 1;
        else if(rectangle.x + rectangle.width > getWidth())dirX = -1;

        if(rectangle.y < 0)dirY = 1;
        else if(rectangle.y + rectangle.height > getHeight())dirY = -1;

        rectangle.x = rectangle.x + dirX * 10;
        rectangle.y = rectangle.y + dirY * 10;;

        repaint();
    }

}
public class CustomPainting {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               final MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
               JFrame frame = new JFrame();
              frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
              frame.add(canvas);
              frame.setVisible(true);
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

              Timer timer = new Timer(200, canvas);
              timer.start();
              new Thread()
              {
                  public void run()
                  {
                      try {
                          canvas.buffImg = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/33400000/Cute-Panda-beautiful-pictures-33434826-500-500.jpg"));
                          MyCanvas.imageLoading = false;
                      } catch (IOException ex) {
                          Logger.getLogger(CustomPainting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                      }
                  }
              }.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is: [`drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage-java.awt.Image-int-int-int-int-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-)

Comment: I believe this method actually re- scales the image to fit inside the rectangle specified, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes you are right, use this instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, java.awt.Color, java.awt.image.ImageObserver)

Answer (score 0):

You can scale or draw a part of an image using Graphics.drawImage as mentioned another answer and according to Java documentation, ImageObserver argument is not needed for BufferedImage so you can just pass null.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

However, my choice would be the clipping drawing region of image instead.
Here is an example you can try:

```
Graphics2D g = BufferedImage.getGraphics;
g.setClip(x, y, width, height);
g.drawImage(sx, sy, x - sx, y - sy, null );
```